# Import-Csv Offset rows

Tags: sql, powershell, csv

I'm Importing multiple CSV files into a SQL database.
What switches or additional functions can I use to skip the first 5 rows on the import?

Ive tried using `Get-Content file.csv | Select -skip 5 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Name`

but not sure how to add it to my code

```cs
$srcDir = "C:\PowerShell\Files"

Write-Output $srcDir

$files  = Get-ChildItem $srcDir -Name -Attributes !Directory 

foreach ($file in $files) {
    echo $file

    $filePath = $srcDir + '\' + $file
    $delimiter = ','
    $addTableName = $file -replace ".csv",""
    $writeTableName = '"' + $addTableName + '"'

    $dt = Import-Csv $filePath -Delimiter $delimiter | Out-DataTable

    Write-Output $writeTableName
    ## Write-Output $dt.Columns
    ## Write-Output $dt.Columns

    Add-SqlTable -ServerInstance "11.22.33.444\MSSQL" -Database "STAGE" -TableName $addTableName -DataTable $dt

    Write-DataTable -ServerInstance "11.22.33.444\MSSQL" -Database "STAGE" -TableName $writeTableName -Data $dt
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `-skip` parameter in `Import-Csv` statement instead of using in `Get-Content`. Something like this:
`Import-Csv file.csv -Header Name | select -Skip 5`

Comment: The issue with using -Header Name is that I don't know the name of the headers per file and there are hundreds of files. I cant hard code them

Comment: You could make the name a wildcard.

Comment: I'm not sure how to I would go about grabbing each column name per file and making it available to be written to the table. 
Sorry still new to powershell and it's taken a while to get this working while understanding

Comment: Yank the first line with `Get-Content` to get the headers, then use Vivek's suggestion to skip the "data" rows.

Comment: Think I'm losing it here 
I've added 
    `$csvColumnNames = (Get-Content $filePath| Select-Object -index 1).Split(",")`
But the -Header won't accept the array unless in this format "col1","col2",

so I revised that and got to this 
`$csvColumnNames = (Get-Content $filePath| Select-Object -index 1).Split(",") -Join """,",""""
        $str = """$csvColumnNames"""`
but it still doesnt like it and piles all column into one 

could someone give me an example, Thanks in advance

Comment: okay guys I just need a small bit of help here. I've scrapped the above 
I need to know why the `-Header` will not accept this array
`$csvColumnNames = (Get-Content $filePath| Select-Object -index 1).Split(",")` 
again all this does is put the column names in a list but I get this error when providing it to the `-Header`
_"Import-Csv : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Header'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again."_